# Null when transforming all the templates from MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, t4

I'm getting a null when running MSBuild with the /t:TransformAll target in a .csproj:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplati‌​ng.targets(396,5): error : Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r [C:\IDB-Git\IDB.Middleware\IDB.MW.Domain\IDB.MW.Domain.csproj]

No clue about what to do now. Is it a bug? How could I workaround this?

The following is an extract of the line 396 of Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets and its context:

```
  <Target Name="ExecuteTransformations" DependsOnTargets="CreateT4ItemLists">

    <TransformTemplates
      TemplatesToProcess="@(T4TransformInputs)"
      IncludeFolders="$(IncludeFolders)"
      DirectiveProcessors="@(DirectiveProcessor)"
      AssemblyReferences="@(T4AssemblyReference)"
      ReferencePaths="@(T4ReferencePath)"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(TrackerLogDirectory)"
      TrackFileAccess="$(TrackFileAccess)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="$(TransformOutOfDateOnly)"
      OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles)"
      ParameterValues="@(T4ParameterValues)"
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a null reference in one of your templates being transformed. The TransformTemplates task will just fail and bubble up any exceptions from the transform of a template fails. The best way to find the culprit is to run the target one at a time for each template you have.

If you really want to validate that the TransformTemplates isn't to blame then you should run MS Build with diagnostic logging and ensure all of the TransformTemplates parameters have sensible values.